# Is it ok asking for the name of the hiring manager? If yes, how to politely ask?

Tags: hiring-process

I'm applying for a company. Usually when I apply they give me many information about the team and hiring manager, and starting from such information I investigate a bit about the hiring manager, the team etc.

This time such a thing didn't happen, I mean they gave me some information, but not some details I'm usually been given. I'd like to know who is the hiring manager, so for example I could look for him in linked in etc.

Is this thing ok? How can I politely ask that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really think it is important?

Comment: Yes, I do. I think it is important to know who are you talking with.

Answer (score 3):

One way to politely ask this might be:

> I was wondering if it is possible to learn more about the team and the hiring manager? This would help me learn more about the organization.

This way you are not directly asking for the name but it is likely that a response would include the name.  You are also broadening your request so it is less focused on the individual but more on the overall team and employer.

Comment: No need for tricks. Just ask the question!!

Answer (score 2):

Of course it's okay to ask.  Working in an office, I see at least 3 emails a week from somebody who has emailed our sales address asking if there are any jobs available.  Even worse than this, we sometimes get a website enquiry asking the same thing.

Speaking personally, it puts me off.  If someone cannot be bothered to phone up and ask for the name / email address of the person in charge of hiring, then it immediately gives the impression that they are a lazy person.  Probably a broad generalisation but that's how it feels.

Pick up the phone, explain that you have applied for a job and would like to know the name of the person in charge of hiring.  Simple as that.  If you can get an email address (you may have pre-interview questions after all) then all the better.

Comment: Isn't it too much eventually contacting the hiring manager by e-mail?

Comment: @user8469759 If you haven't been granted an interview, yes but if in the future you may need it ie, you were given an interview and were told you'd get a confirmation letter but received nothing so would need to chase up.

Comment: So in summary, for the future in general. There's nothing wrong with asking more info about who the hiring manager is (i.e. the name etc) for the purpose I stated in my question, is not something that would be interpreted as creepy etc. Is perfectly normal, right?

Answer (score 2):

> Please could I take the name of your hiring manager, for future reference?

or:

> Would you be able to connect me with your company's hiring manager, please?

It's a pretty simple question, and it's traditional to know who the hiring manager is, if you are looking to be hired.

You don't need to overthink this.

Just ask the question.